# DynamoDB - What is the --max-items option of Query API on aws-cli?

Tags: amazon-web-services

Query API on aws-cli has the --limit and --max-items option, but looks like both options are same.

What is the difference between these two options?

Also, I am using the AWS SDK for Java, but I did not find the --max-items option. Does this option exists?

Comment: --max-items (integer)

The total number of items to return. If the total number of items available is more than the value specified in max-items then a NextToken will be provided in the output that you can use to resume pagination. This NextToken response element should not be used directly outside of the AWS CLI.  http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/dynamodb/query.html

Comment: Thanks! But I had misunderstood. Query API on aws-cli does not have the --limit option. --limit option is the parameter, which means to limit the maximum number of items to scan.